# Is there a way to change the default sorting of a Facebook Guestbook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-integration

I have a Facebook guestbook (aka "Facebook Comments Section" aka "Facebook Social Plugin") integrated in a Drupal website of mine, and the default sorting order is 'Social Status' (comparable to most number of likes/votes/whatever I think).
I've searched the Internet to see if this sorting order can be changed to the more logical 'Reverse Chronologic', but apparently this can't be changed, quite surprisingly.

The guestbook is integrated by using html markup, so maybe there exists a (hidden) property to achieve this after all... ?

I'm not getting my hopes up, but I have to try the StackExchange network at least ;)

Comment: I have the same problem. Would be great if someone knew a way. Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686094/facebook-comments-plugin-how-to-sort-comments

Comment: Hi Hermund, adding the `data-order-by="reverse_time"` attribute in the html markup actually worked !  Please put your comment as an answer, explaining the attribute, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link provided in the comment of Hermund provided the correct answer to my question. Hermund hasn't put his comment as an answer, therefore I'll answer it myself as to help others stumbling on this question.

**Solution:**

Add `data-order-by="reverse_time"` as an attribute to the HTML markup on your site.

**Example:**

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.yoursite.be/blahblah/" 
data-num-posts="5" data-width="600" data-colorscheme="light" data-mobile="false" 
data-order-by="reverse_time">&nbsp;</div>
```